# Hibernate cascade save

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have a problem with Hibernate. 
See [my data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUZ4A.png)

I have class - "Ticket"...

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "ticketComposition",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ticketId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tripsSiteId")})
private Set<TripsSite> tripsSites = new HashSet<TripsSite>();
```

and when  I'm trying to save new ticket...

```
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    User user = userService.findBySSO(userName);
    ticket.setUser(user);


    ticket.setTripsSites(new HashSet<>(tripsSites));

    persist(ticket);
```

I get the following error:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sbb`.`ticketcomposition`, CONSTRAINT `ticket` FOREIGN KEY (`ticketId`) REFERENCES `ticket` (`id`))

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like this defined on the `TicketSite` entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="tripSites")
private Set<Trip> trips = new HashSet<Trip>();
```

While persisting, you have to set the dependencies on both sides of the `@ManyToMany` mapping:

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
User user = userService.findBySSO(userName);
ticket.setUser(user);

ticket.setTripsSites(new HashSet<>(tripsSites));

for(TicketSite ticketSite: ticketSites){
   ticketSite.getTickets().add(ticket);
} 

persist(ticket);
```

I am assuming that the `ticketSites` set has been previously retrieved from the database and has been persisted before this transactional method started.

Comment: yes, i get tripsSites.  List<TripsSite> tripsSites = getEntityManager()
                .createNativeQuery(nativeQuery,TripsSite.class)
                .setParameter("st1",st1)
                .setParameter("st2",st2)
                .setParameter("dirId",dirId)
                .setParameter("carId",carId)
                .setParameter("siteId",siteId)
                .getResultList();